# Why doesn't BindingList<T> have to fully implement its interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

`BindingList<T>` implements `IBindingList`.  One of the methods on `IBindingList` is

```
void ApplySort(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction);
```

But `BindingList<T>` doesn't implement this method.  Instead it implements

```
protected virtual void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction);
```

Obviously `ApplySortCore` has a different name and is not public, so I don't see how it could satisfy the requirement of the `IBindingList` interface yet this is the closest thing to what `IBindingList` actually calls for.

So how is it possible for this class to get away with not fully implementing its interfaces?

Comment: Where did you get this info? msdn doc lists it under explicit interface implementations.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358213(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LorentzVedeler I see now.  I was just hitting F12 in visual studio.  But I went to the docs and I see now that it's implemented explicitly.  You just can't tell that from hitting F12. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `BindingList` uses explicit interface implementation to hide interface members.

Try this

```
interface IX
{
    public string Var {get;}
}

public class X : IX
{
    string IX.Var { get { return "x"; } }
}

public class Y
{
    public Y()
    {
        X x = new X();
        string s = x.Var; // Var is not visible and gives a compilation error.

        string s2 = ((IX)x).Var; // this works. Var is not hidden when using interface directly.
    }
}
```

Comment: The term is _explicit interface implementation_. MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks.  I was hitting F12 to see what was in the class, but I didn't realize that it wouldn't list explicitly implemented methods and didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The BindingList explicintly implement the interface here is msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, that is why you don't see it on the class.

To be able to call the method you need to cast the object to  IBindingList first.

Answer (score 1):

BindingList<T> *does* in fact implement ApplySort, but it does so as an explicit interface implementation. What this means is that if you have a variable of type BindingList<T> you won't see an ApplySort method on it, but if you *cast* that variable to IBindingList you'll then see the ApplySort method. Explicit interface implementations are only visible when you're looking at an object as that interface.

If you look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and scroll down to the heading 'Explicit Interface Implementations', you'll see ApplySort listed there (as well as many other methods).